# Filtrar interfaces dependiendo lo requerido en linux con C

Tags: c, lista

ya con ayuda de aqui mismo de pude obtener un programa que me lista todas las interfaces de red, el programa es el siguiente:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE     /* To get defns of NI_MAXSERV and NI_MAXHOST */
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/if_link.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
struct ifaddrs *addrs, *tmp;
getifaddrs(&addrs);
tmp = addrs;

/*solo imprime el nombre de los puertos disponibles*/
while (tmp)
{
    if (tmp->ifa_addr && tmp->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_PACKET)
        printf("%s\n", tmp->ifa_name);

    tmp = tmp->ifa_next;
}
freeifaddrs(addrs);
}
```

lo que me faltaria es que ahora me pida las parecidas y devolver en un arreglo las interfaces que se parecen (es decir, inician con lo mismo).

Por ejemplo, sería como pedir :

Dame las interfaces que comienzan en "eth". El resultado podría ser un arreglo con los strings: eth0, eth1, eth3.

tengo entendido que la interfas que despliga la hace por medio del **ifa_name**, pero como hago la comparacion con todo lo que inicio con **eth** por ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr el objetivo, pasaremos el *prefijo* a comparar como argumento en la línea de comandos a tu programa.  Siendo este el caso, la respuesta a tu pregunta en realidad se compone de 2 partes.

La primera es

## Leer los argumentos de la línea de comandos

Cuando escribes la función principal de un programa en C, usualmente ves una de estas dos definiciones:

- `int main(void)`
- `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

La segunda forma recibe los argumentos que se han pasado al programa desde la línea de comandos, y el número de argumentos especificados (los argumentos se separan por espacios).

Así, los argumentos de `main` son:

- `int argc` - El número de argumentos que se han pasado al programa cuando se ejecuta. Ese valor es por lo menos `1`.
- `char **argv` - Es un puntero a `char *`. De manera alternativa puede ser: `char *argv[]`, que significa un 'array of `char *`'. Este es un arreglo de punteros a cadenas terminadas en nulo.

#### Ejemplo básico:

Por ejemplo, podrías imprimir los argumentos que tu programa recibe con este programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Utilizando GCC 4.5 para compilar este código en un archivo llamado `args.c` produciría por defecto un ejecutable llamado `a.out`.

```
[jachguate@lilun c_code]$ gcc -std=c99 args.c
```

Al ejecutarlo...

```
[jachguate@lilun c_code]$ ./a.out hello there
argv[0]: ./a.out
argv[1]: hello
argv[2]: there
```

Como puedes ver, en `argv`, el primer elemento `argv[0]` es el nombre del programa mismo (no es algo que esté definido en un estándar, pero es común que así funcione). Los argumentos que has recibido se encuentran en `argv[1]` y siguientes.

Esto es bastante rudimentario, pero funciona para casos simples (como este).

La otra parte es:

## Comparar si una cadena de caracteres inicia con otra:

Una vez tienes el argumento, ahora básicamente necesitamos saber si el nombre de la interfaz que estamos procesando dentro del ciclo `while`, almacenado en `ifa_name` inicia con dicho *prefijo*, para ello podemos valernos de la función [`strncmp`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strncmp.htm), que básicamente compara los primeros n bytes de dos cadenas y nos devuelve 0 si las cadenas son iguales.  La forma de llamarla sería con un if, en una estructura similar a esta:

```
if strncmp(prefijo, cadena, strlen(prefijo)) == 0 {
    printf("cadena SI inicia con prefijo!");
}
```

## Ahora juntemos las piezas

Poner esto junto en código es una tarea que queda al lector, pero básicamente lo que yo haría es seguir los siguientes pasos:

- Comprobar el número de argumentos recibidos. Si no se ha pasado ningún argumento al programa, informar al usuario de la forma de uso y salir con error (el resultado de main podría ser 1 y no 0, por ejemplo)
- Dentro del while, añadir con un operador lógico `&&` (and) la condición de comparación con el prefijo, al final del `if` ya existente. De manera que se impriman solo las que cumplen todas las condiciones.